# How to get Rotation events on ViewController within UITabBarController->UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I wanna show a full-screen Landscape view whenever the user rotates the iOS device from portrait to landscape, where the portrait view is a view within a TabBar and NavigationController.

However, willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: is never called. I tested also to add the ViewController as Observer of UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification events, but this notification is called also with undefined orientation.

What would be the best and easiest way for the given task?

Answer (score 1):

There are also `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` notifications.

The `userInfo` dictionary contains an NSNumber object that encapsulates a `UIInterfaceOrientation` value. Use `UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey` to access this value

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification 
                                               object:nil];

- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification{   
    NSNumber *num = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"UIApplicationStatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey"];
    NSLog(@"%d", [num intValue]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good hint. However, UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification is never called, as the TabBarController doesn't directly respond to orientation changes (it allows only portrait) and hence the status bar is never rotated.